# How to pass any Enum as a function argument in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, enums

This code is similar to an answer posted in 2018 to a question about how you can pass any Enum as an argument to a function. It works as presented but I would like it eg to print Weekday.DAYOFF.MyString . Can someone tell me how to do that please. Substituting myString for name in the method doesn't work. There's something I am not getting about visibility maybe.

```
enum class Status {
    OPEN, CLOSED
}

enum class Weekday(val MyString: String){
    WORKDAY("str1"),
    DAYOFF("str2")
}

fun <E : Enum<E>> methodWithKotlinEnumAsParameter(arg : E)
{
    println(arg.name)
}
```

Now, if you for example call methodWithKotlinEnumAsParameter(Weekday.DAYOFF), it will print DAYOFF to the console.

Comment: You can't do this in a generic way. This function doesn't know which enum type is passed to it, so it doesn't know there's a `MyString` property that it can access. What would you expect to happen if `Status.OPEN` is passed to it? There would be no `MyString`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `methodWithKotlinEnumAsParameter` takes an `Enum`, i.e. the parent of both `Status` and `Weekday`, so you can only use methods and properties exposed by `Enum`, unless you cast the value to the specific type of enum you want:

```
fun <E : Enum<E>> methodWithKotlinEnumAsParameter(arg : E) {
    if (arg is Weekday) {
        println(arg.myString)   
    } else {
        println(arg.name)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're only interested in a custom string representation, you can override the `toString` method:

```
enum class Weekday(val myString: String){ // the property should be snakeCase according to standard conventions
    WORKDAY("str1"),
    DAYOFF("str2");

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$name($myString)"
    }
}
```

Comment: No it is the first solution I am seeking. If you pass in an instance,  Weekday.DAYOFF eg it can .name it but it will not recognise myString,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a function that takes `Weekday` specific, pass it to the arguments this way:

```
fun methodWithKotlinEnumAsParameter(weekday: Weekday) {
     println(weekday.MyString) //You can access `MyString` now
}
```

But if you want this function to accept any type of enums like the way you presented in your question, then you will not get access to `MyString` because the compiler does not know if the passed enum is a `Weekday`, it may be something else that does not have `MyString` property.